# Combining Signer Tasks on Composite Template

Tags: docusignapi

I am running some tests with the DocuSign API via PostMan for a solution proof of concept. My goal is to create a single envelope with multiple documents, each assigned to its own template.

Our goal is to create a dynamic envelope of templates as needed; i.e. sometimes we will only need to put one template into the envelope, other times we might need five or six. The tricky bit is that a single person might be a recipient on multiple documents at once. We are looking to see if its possible to configure the envelope so that they can sign all of their documents at once.

I've been able to use the API to generate an envelope with two documents assigned to two templates. Each template has three recipients (the same three people for both document). The envelope is automatically assigned to the first batch of recipients for the first template (Recipients A and B since they both have a routing order of 1). But when the recipient goes to sign the envelope, they only see the signature option for the first document and don't have an option to sign the second document.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

I'm testing this process in Postman. Below is a copy of the POST body. I appreciate any advice.

```
{
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "document": {
            "documentBase64": "<<BinaryDataA>>",
            "documentId": "1",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "name": "Test Document A"
        },
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "<<recipient_a_email>>",
                            "name": "<<recipient_a_name>>",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Client A",
                            "routingOrder":"1"
                        },
                        {
                            "email": "<<recipient_b_email>>",
                            "name": "<<recipient_b_name>>",
                            "recipientId": "2",
                            "roleName": "Client B",
                            "routingOrder":"1"
                        },
                        {
                            "email": "<<recipient_c_email>>",
                            "name": "<<recipient_c_name>>",
                            "recipientId": "3",
                            "roleName": "Internal Review",
                            "routingOrder":"2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "<<templateID_1>>"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "document": {
            "documentBase64": "<<BinaryDataB>>",
            "documentId": "2",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "name": "Test Landscape Document"
        },
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "<<recipient_a_email>>",
                            "name": "<<recipient_a_name>>",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Client A",
                            "routingOrder":"1"
                        },
                        {
                            "email": "<<recipient_b_email>>",
                            "name": "<<recipient_b_name>>",
                            "recipientId": "2",
                            "roleName": "Client B",
                            "routingOrder":"1"
                        },
                        {
                            "email": "<<recipient_c_email>>",
                            "name": "<<recipient_c_name>>",
                            "recipientId": "3",
                            "roleName": "Internal Review",
                            "routingOrder":"2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "<<templateID_2>>"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"status": "sent",
"emailSubject":"Please Sign this Document"}
```

Comment: seems you are not using JSON arrays correctly. The serverTempaltes and inlinteTemplates are arrays that can include many templates, but they should not repeat twice like you do

Comment: Hi Inbar, Are you able to provide an example. I have tried adjusting my code a few times so that the template arrays contained multiple items, but I am getting an error response saying that the 'Template was not provided'. 
I'm also unsure how I would be able to list multiple templates in an array and also assign each template a document?

Comment: would you be open to using an SDK? SDKs abstract the need to write pure JSON with objects from whichever language you use and help solve these types of problems.

Comment: I am running my tests in pure JSON because that is what our integration software will use when integrating with DocuSign (it will generate a JSON payload to send to DocuSign). 

I've been following the CURL examples on this page since that is essentially the same concept
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-adding-document-template

Comment: posted an example as an answer, replace the templateIDs with your IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following JSON body allowed me to create an envelope with two Documents, each assigned to a different template. I did have to define the recipient information per composite item, but DocuSign recognised that they were the same person and they were able to sign both documents in a single session.

The blog (https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-why-use-composite-templates) helped describe how composite envelopes are structured which was a big help.

```
{
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "compositeTemplateId": "1",
        "document": {
            "documentBase64": "<<BinaryDataA>>",
            "documentId": "1",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "name": "Test Document A"
        },
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "<<TemplateIDA>>"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "<<recipient_A_Email>>",
                            "name": "<<recipient_A_Name>>",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Client A",
                            "routingOrder":"1"
                        },
                        {
                            "email": "<<recipient_B_Email>>",
                            "name": "<<recipient_B_Name>>",
                            "recipientId": "2",
                            "roleName": "Client B",
                            "routingOrder":"1"
                        },
                        {
                            "email": "<<recipient_C_Email>>",
                            "name": "<<recipient_C_Name>>",
                            "recipientId": "3",
                            "roleName": "Internal Review",
                            "routingOrder":"2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "compositeTemplateId": "2",
        "document": {
            "documentBase64": "<<BinaryDataB>>",
            "documentId": "2",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "name": "Test Document B"
        },
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "<<TemplateIDB>>"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "<<recipient_A_Email>>",
                            "name": "<<recipient_A_Name>>",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "roleName": "Client A",
                            "routingOrder":"1"
                        },
                        {
                            "email": "<<recipient_B_Email>>",
                            "name": "<<recipient_B_Name>>",
                            "recipientId": "2",
                            "roleName": "Client B",
                            "routingOrder":"1"
                        },
                        {
                            "email": "<<recipient_C_Email>>",
                            "name": "<<recipient_C_Name>>",
                            "recipientId": "3",
                            "roleName": "Internal Review",
                            "routingOrder":"2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"status": "sent",
"emailSubject":"Please Sign this Document",
"emailBlurb":"This is a test email blurb"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (taken out of Gil's [Composite Template Blog Post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-why-use-composite-templates))

{

```
    "emailSubject": "Please sign your lease agreement.",
    "emailBlurb": "Each tenant must sign individual lease.",
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "document": {
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "Property-A",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "documentBase64": "JVBERi...NCg=="
        }
    },
    {
        "serverTemplates": [{
        "sequence": "1",
        "templateId": "E5577130-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-95DD79644971"
        }],
        "inlineTemplates": [{
        "recipients": {
            "signers": [{
            "email": "wile.e.coyote@example.com",
            "name": "Wile E. Coyote",
            "roleName": "Tenant"
            }]
        },
        "sequence": "2"
        }]
    },
    {
        "serverTemplates": [{
        "sequence": "1",
        "templateId": "E5577130-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-95DD79644971"
        }],
        "inlineTemplates": [{
        "recipients": {
            "signers": [{
            "email": "hunter_of_rabbits@example.com",
            "name": "Elmer Fudd",
            "roleName": "Tenant"
            }]
        },
        "sequence": "2"
        }]
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In the example above, the documents and templates (server and inline) are listed as individual parts of the composite template array. When I do this, Postman throws an error saying that no template was provided for the document, and is only fixed when I put a server template value into the same array part as the document. 

The example provided is also used to send two copies of the same document (generated by a template) and have it signed by different people. Are you aware of an example where I can send in multiple documents and have them signed by the same people?

Comment: this was just a snippet, it's not the full deal. 
I wonder if you would like to start simple, and not use templates at all, see you can do what you want that way, what is the reason you want a template?

Comment: Thanks Inbar. I was able to get it working thanks to you and the blow

Comment: glad to hear that, would you mind marking this as answered?